# What are the differences between didFinishLaunchingWithOption and viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, viewdidload

What is the difference between the two methods `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` and `viewDidLoad`?

The former is a method of `AppDlegate.m`
and the latter is a method of `ViewController.m`, but both of them perform the same mission of loading the UIs onto the view.

Answer (score 5):

The `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is a `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol method that gets called when iOS has finished setting up an area for your App to run and is the insertion point for you, the developer, to load a view controller, etc.

The `viewDidLoad` method on the other hand is a method of the `UIViewController` class that gets called when an instance of `UIViewController` gets its view loaded into memory. From Apple's documentation:

> Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
>
> **Discussion** 
>   This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is
>   called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib
>   file or created programmatically in the loadView method. You usually
>   override this method to perform additional initialization on views
>   that were loaded from nib files.

Comment: but if I want to load a UIButton onto the view, I can put the code in both the viewDidLoad and the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Is that right?

Comment: No, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is for Application level setup. If you need to modify the subviews for a particular view controller then you need to do that in viewDidLoad. The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method has a twenty (20) second limitation on its total execution time, after 20 seconds your App gets killed by iOS so it's a good idea to get in the habit of avoiding putting code in this method if it can go elsewhere.

Comment: That's really useful and especially the 20 seconds stuff. Thx very much!